# Linq group join failing, if the result has empty rows

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm quite new to using Linq queries, and I'm trying to do a group join between two data tables ( to simulate a left join in sql ), which is failing if some of the rows miss values.

I've tried the query below:

```
(From date_amotiq 
In amotiq_data_dt.AsEnumerable 
Group Join v05_va33_data In v05_join_va33_zalvunloading.AsEnumerable 
    On date_amotiq("MATNR").ToString Equals v05_va33_data("ALV_PN").ToString 
    And date_amotiq("KDMAT").ToString Equals v05_va33_data("CUST_PN").ToString  
    And date_amotiq("UIP_Formatted").ToString 
Equals v05_va33_data("Unloading_Point").ToString Into main_sht_data = Group 
From v05_va33_data in main_sht_data.DefaultIfEmpty() 
Select main_sheet_dt.Clone.LoadDataRow(New Object()
    {"RO1W", 
    date_amotiq("MATNR"), date_amotiq("KDMAT"),date_amotiq("UIP_Formatted"), 
    date_amotiq("RDATUM"), "", 
    main_sht_data.FirstOrDefault().Item(0)
    },False))
.CopyToDataTable
```

I know that "main_sht_data" is generated as an enumerable and I've tried to get the values with FirstOrDefault and ElementOrDefault, which return a datarow, but it fails as soon as I hit an empty row.

Could you please assist?

Comment: It is the ToString() that is causing the issue.  You can use a Where to eliminate the nulls.  Also cast sometimes works From :  v05_va33_data("ALV_PN").ToString To :  (string)v05_va33_data("ALV_PN")  On DateTime you do not need to use anything.  You can compare the DataTime objects directly.

Comment: Hi Sorry for misleading. Date is romanian for data. So date_amotiq, would be te same as data_amotiq, it's no date field. Just a normal string. I cleared the .tostring from the comparison, but I still get the issue. The problem seems to be with the last part "main_sht_data.FirstOrDefault().Item(0)". If I remove the "Item(0)" my cells are filled with "System.Data.Datarow", so the type of the element in the query. Otherwise, I get the error.

Comment: Why do you need Item(0) along with FirstOrdDefault()?  Remove the Item(0).  Or use (main_sht_data == null)? string.Empty : main_sht_data.FirstOrDefault().Item(0)

Comment: If I remove the Item(0) then the result written in the new data table is just "system.data.datarow". If I use FirstOrDefault() together with Item(0) I get the actual value of that data row, if it's not empty. For example, I should get the answer "agreement no.....", but I get "system.data.datarow" if I remove the item(0) tag

Comment: If it is a DataRow then you should use String.Join(",", main_sht_data.FirstOrDefault().ItemArray).  Item(0) is giving only the first column of the data row.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error. If I don't have any corresponding data in v05_va33_data, for the join conditions I get "Anonymously Hosted Dynamic methods Assembly" and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I've tried the syntax above as well. I wouldn't mind getting the first column as a start, but I need to get passed the fact that some of the rows will have empty cells.

Comment: The use a Where to filter the null data before going to the join.

Comment: This is not C# language, please fix your sample or the tag.

Comment: Sorry. Changed it now. It's supposed to be VB, used in the UiPath Studio

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by using if(v05_va33_data is nothing,"",v05_va33_data("Sales_Doc_Type"), and so on, for all fields which could be empty.